# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg '

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python

```
$ etcdctl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 28, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound import CommandNotFound
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 19, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.db import SqliteDatabase
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/db.py", line 5, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'.
```

I was trying to see if etcdctl would work. I've also tried this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41986507/unable-to-set-default-python-version-to-python3-in-ubuntu#:~:text=Type%20alias%20python%3Dpython3%20on,your%20alias%20should%20be%20permanent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41986507/unable-to-set-default-python-version-to-python3-in-ubuntu#:%7E:text=Type%20alias%20python%3Dpython3%20on,your%20alias%20should%20be%20permanent).

Comment: There's a typo in the command - it should be `etcdctl`, not `etcdclt`.

Comment: Did you downvote the question just for that? The error stands regardless of the typo, which I've fixed in the question.

Comment: Down-voted for insufficient details. What version of ubuntu are you running? What are you trying to do, what is the expected result? Why would etcdctl work, did you just install it, or are you trying to see if etcdctl is already available on the system? In _that_ case you should run `which etcdctl`, for example. Here's a good read: https://d.cxcore.net/Eric%20S%20Raymond/How%20To%20Ask%20Questions%20The%20Smart%20Way.pdf

Answer (score 1):

based on these answers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69949591/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-apt-pkg-installing-deadsnakes-repository
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13708180/python-dev-installation-error-importerror-no-module-named-apt-pkg

I tried the following and it seemed to work:

1. Use the below to find the relevant `apt_pkg` file:

   ```bash
   ls /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/*apt_pkg*
   ```
2. Make the necessary symbolic link. For example in my case, it was:

   ```bash
   sudo ln -s /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so
   ```